# Is "spaced by 1 meter" correct English?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Suppose that the distance between A and B is 1m, is it correct and natural to say

> A and B are **spaced by** 1 meter

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As pointed out by @J.R it seems that **spaced by** is a correct expression.

Here is another variant:

According to Oxford Dictionary, you can use the particle **apart** instead of **by**.

[**space**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/space) VERB

> Position (two or more items) at a distance from one another.
>   *the poles are **spaced** 3m **apart***

Comment: Yep, "spaced [x] meters apart" definitely sounds more natural to me (in US English, at least... or northeast US English, anyway).

Comment: Just advice make sure they understand compeltely. For example spaced end to end or start to start? For example this could happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef93WmlEho0

Answer (score 16):

Using ***spaced by x*** where *x* refers to some quantity is actually fairly common in scientific literature.

Some examples:

> The black vertical lines are guides to the eye and [they are spaced by](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms7772/figures/3) 0.7 ps.
>
> Each aperture is a few metres across and they are [spaced by](https://www.ras.org.uk/library/information-sheets/121-astrobiology) a few tens of metres.
>
> On the front surface two semicircular electrodes with a radius of 1 mm are [spaced by](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/666b/733372d4d7a900f1c314a1b4b8ee3d71f942.pdf) 100 *μ*m.
>
> Absorption does not accumulate between the spectral holes because
>   they are [spaced by](https://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=918276) only a few times the minimum observed
>   spectral-hole width.

Comment: My feeling is that "spaced by" works better for multiple objects all at the same spacing, as in your first two examples. It doesn't quite feel right for only two objects. Not sure why...

Comment: @AndyT - I agree that it has a slightly awkward feel, although I think it can work in technical contexts.

Answer (score 7):

It's understandable, but doesn't feel quite right. I would prefer either

A and B are spaced apart by 1 meter

or

A and B are spaced 1 meter apart

However, assuming that you are measuring in SI units and not using the size of your gas or electric meter as a unit of length, then the word is METRE.

Comment: Metre vs meter is British English vs American English.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that *metre* is the "international standard" and "meter" is some kind of aberration.  *Meter* simply happens to be the US spelling, just like *theater/re*, *fiber/re*, *centre/re*, etc.

Comment: @stangdon Meter is the German spelling, which American and Phillipines English borrowed.  The original spelling in French is what got borrowed by every other English dialect.

Comment: @stangdon "Metre" is the BIPM spelling ([International Bureau of Weights and Measures](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-2.html)) - which is the closest to international agreement we'll get on these things (USA is a signatory to the Metre Convention that formed the BIPM). Not that it means "Meter" is incorrect, it is obviously fine in AmE contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad English in the sense that it is confusing and creates ambiguity. Although I can't give you the exact grammatic rules for prepositions (i.e. by), it 'feels' as though there is a word missing from your sentence, hence the ambiguity.

One would normally say: 
- A and B are spaced 1 meter apart (singular case),
- NN are spaced by 1 meter intervals,  (generally a plural context)
- or by/at/in equally spaced gaps, etc.

Comment: And an afterthought …. all of @JR's examples using 'spaced by' suggest a plural context, whereas Naetmul's question referred to a single instance.

Comment: What do you mean with "a plural context"? Notice that OP mentioned two items and this phrase taken from J.R's answer refers to two items too: "On the front surface two semicircular electrodes with a radius of 1 mm are spaced by 100 μm."

Comment: RubioRic, first, scientific journals are noted for quality of science, not quality of English!! In those examples, most numbers can (ambiguously!) be read as multiple spaces. However that specific case is not even grammatical, so is an invalid example even though understandable! -  It should say 'There ARE two semi-circular electrodes OF radius 1mm on the front surface (of what?), which are spaced 100 microns apart  (rather than spaced by!).  Incidentally, Scientific journals and Instruction manuals are clearer when written in present tense, instead of opaque continuous tenses often adopted.

Comment: Notice that OP has not stated any context. Maybe he/she is writing a paper. Scientific texts may use non-conversational English but that does not imply a poor quality [Note: I've not downvoted you]

Comment: How is there ambiguity? I can only think of one way of interpreting the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

These variants all sound "natural":

A and B:

- are spaced by 1 meter
- are 1 meter apart
- are set 1 meter apart
- are separated by 1 meter
- have a 1 meter separation
- have a 1 meter offset
- are offset by 1 meter

Answer (score 1):

"Spaced apart" may be commonly used, but it is a horrible grammatical error called a pleonasm (like "round circle", "kicking with your feet", "foot pedal" - "pedis" is the genitive of the Latin word "pes" for "foot").

"Spaced" by itself already implies "apart", so "spaced apart" is double.