# Phrase request: Scale units

Tags: phrase-request

Can you help me to think of another ways to say:

> "The gauge has a scale with units at a distance of every 10 cm."?

Are the following sentences correct:

> "The gauge scale is divided by 10 cm intervals.",
>
> "The gauge scale has a mark every 10 cm."?

What is the most common and natural way to say this in English?

Comment: Related: [Spaced by 1 metre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176416/is-spaced-by-1-meter-correct-english/176441#176441).

Comment: The gauge has a scale **graduated** in 10 cm increments.

Comment: What kind of a scale or gauge is it? I think a picture might help.

Comment: "The gauge scale is divided **into** 10 cm intervals" is better.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to say it.

> The gauge has a scale with [markings](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scale%20markings%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) set at 10 cm intervals.